# Can we apply Instagram effects on a video using PHP?

Tags: php, video, instagram

As we all know, it is possible to add/edit effect on a image using php. But can we also do the same thing for a video? I have done some searching for this but no results.

I am [giving a link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-instagram-filters-with-php--net-24504) which shows how to show effects on an image and which is working fine, but what about video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this image effects with [**GD library**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).

> PHP is not limited to creating just HTML output. It can also be used
>   to create and manipulate image files in a variety of different image
>   formats, including GIF, PNG, JPEG, WBMP, and XPM. Even more
>   convenient, PHP can output image streams directly to a browser. You
>   will need to compile PHP with the GD library of image functions for
>   this to work. GD and PHP may also require other libraries, depending
>   on which image formats you want to work with.

But unfortunately there is no library available in php to <strike>Video accessing and adding effects.</strike>